# How to override nested child component styling in MaterialUI v5?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a **ToggleButton** component that has custom styling. I want to make that Toggle Button component look differently only when it's used as a child (inside) a **ToggleButtonGroup**. Here is how I'd call the **ToggleButtonGroup** component:

```
        <ToggleButtonGroup onChange={()=>{}} ariaLabel='platform'>
          <ToggleButton label='Japan' value='1' selected={true}/>
          <ToggleButton label='China' value='2' selected={false}/>
          <ToggleButton label='Brazil' value='3' selected={false}/>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Here is the code for my **ToggleButtonGroup** component:

```
const StyledToggleGroup = styled(ToggleOptionsGroup)(
    ({ theme: { palette, spacing } }) => ({
      height: spacing(10),
      borderRadius: '6px',
      boxShadow: 'none',
  
      '&:hover': {
        boxShadow: 'none',
      },
      '&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-root':{
        gap: '0px'
      },
      '&.MuiToggleButton-standard':{
        backgroundColor:'red',
      },
      '&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor:'green',
      }
    })
  );


const ToggleButtonGroup:React.FC<ToggleButtonGroupProps> = ({children, onChange, ariaLabel}) =>{

    return(
        <StyledToggleGroup
        exclusive
        onChange={onChange}
        aria-label={ariaLabel}>
        {children}
      </StyledToggleGroup>
    )
}
```

However, the last two classes:

```
      '&.MuiToggleButton-standard':{
        backgroundColor:'red',
      },
      '&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor:'green',
      }
```

don't really change anything.

How can I change the styling of my **ToggleButton** component only when it's passed as a child to the **ToggleButtonGroup** component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that class names are correct according to MUI [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/toggle-button-group/), the posted code should just need to specify these as children of `StyledToggleGroup` with a descendant   [combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#descendant_combinator) after `&` for the styles to work:

Tested in a simple demo here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e9tyca?file=src/App.js)

```
  "& .MuiToggleButton-standard": {
    backgroundColor: "hotpink",
  },
  "& .MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped.Mui-selected": {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
  },
```